# Design and encapsulation: Dictionary with multiple class instances, or one instance with many internal dictionaries

Tags: oop, dictionary, encapsulation

I have a Calculator class which takes data of n types, and returns a value based on some calculation on the data.  I am generating the data in my Main class, and I'm faced with two options on how to design the Calculator class.

First option:

```
public class Main 
{
    Dictionary<DataType, Calculator> dataTypeToCalculator = new Dictionary<DataType, Calculator>()
    void RecordResult(Data data) 
    {
        Calculator calculator = dataTypeToCalculator[data.DataType]; //assume this exists
        int result = calculator.Calculate(data);
        StoreResult(result); //pretend this is implemented, it stores the result somewhere in Main object
    }
}

public class Calculator 
{
    int field1 = 1;
    int field2 = 2;
    int Calculate(Data data) 
    {
        return data.Value + field1 + field2;
    }
}
```

Second option:

```
public class Main 
{
    Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
    void RecordResult(Data data) 
    {
        calculator.Calculate(data);
    }
}

public class Calculator 
    {
    Dictionary<DataType, int> dataTypeToField1 = new Dictionary<DataType, int>();
    Dictionary<DataType, int> dataTypeToField2 = new Dictionary<DataType, int>();
    void Calculate(Data data) 
    {
        int field1 = dataTypeToField1[data.DataType];
        int field2 = dataTypeToField2[data.DataType];
        return data.Value + field1 + field2;
    }
}
```

I have a couple of clean classes that don't have any internal fields where I can have one instance and just pass Data to it from the Main class and have it handle the different DataTypes.  However, I have other classes with multiple necessary fields, and creating an internal dictionary for each one seems bad.  Is there a standard "best practice" for this type of situation?  In this example, I want the Calculator to encapsulate all of the calculating tasks, and not have to rely on the Main class to separate the data.  However, this just doesn't seem right to me when my class has many fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case is really specific one, so I suppose there is no any "best practice" that fits your problem. Fortunately, there are general principles with my favorite one [`Single Responsibility Principle (SRP)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) from [`SOLID`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles.

If I correctly understood your case, you have:

- `Calculator` responsible for doing computations
- `Factory` responsible for creation of `Calculator` instances
- `Configuration` that contains data for `Calculators`
- `Repository` responsible for data persistence

So I suggest creating separate classes responsible for specific functionalities: Calculator, CalculatorFactory, CalulatorConfiguration, CalculationResultsRepository, ...

Create a classes with more than one responsibility usually leads to the code which is difficult to manage, test and future development.